# '11' sequence detector systemverilog

Tags: system-verilog, sequence-detector

I wrote a program for a '11' sequence detector to be implemented by both Moore and Mealy machine. The problem statement is for z to be asserted high after x has been high for 2 cycles. I've attached my implementation below, but what I am seeing is that for both FSMs, z is asserted one cycle too early. Can anyone spot the error in my FSM or code? I would really appreciate any input on what I may be doing wrong! Thanks

FSM:

[image]

Systemverilog code:
Moore:

```
module moore_fsm  
(input bit clk, reset, x,  
  output bit z);  

  typedef enum bit [1:0] {A, B, C} states;  
  states current_state, next_state;  

  always_ff @(posedge clk, negedge reset) begin  
  if (~reset)  
  current_state <= A;  
  else current_state <= next_state;  
  end  

  always_comb begin  
  case (current_state)  
  A:begin     
        z=0;   
        if (x==0) begin  
      next_state = A;  
        end  
        else begin  
        next_state = B;  
        end  
        end  
  B:  begin  
        z=0;  
        if (x==1) begin  
        next_state = C;  
        end  
        else begin  
        next_state = A;  
        end   
        end  
  C: begin    
      z=1;  
     if (x==1) begin  
      next_state = C;  
      end  
      else begin  
     next_state = A;  
      end  
      end  
  endcase  
  end  


  endmodule:moore_fsm
```

Mealy:

```
module mealy_fsm  
(input bit clk, reset, x,  
  output bit z);  

   typedef enum bit {A, B} states;  
    states current_state, next_state;  

  always_ff @(posedge clk, negedge reset) begin  
  if (~reset)  
  current_state <= A;  
  else current_state <= next_state;  
  end  

  always_comb  
  begin  
  case (current_state)  
  A: if (x==1) begin  
      next_state = B;  
        z=0;  
        end  
        else begin  
        next_state = A;  
        z=0;  
        end  
    B: if (x==1) begin  
        next_state = B;  
        z=1;  
        end  
        else begin  
        next_state = A;  
        z=0;  
        end    
  endcase  
  end  

endmodule:mealy_fsm
```

Testbench

```
module moore_mealy ();  

bit clk, reset, x, moore_z, mealy_z;  

moore_fsm dut1 (clk, reset, x, moore_z);  
mealy_fsm dut2 (clk, reset, x, mealy_z);  


initial begin  
reset = 1;  
 #1 reset = 0;  
 #1 reset = 1;  
 #5 x=0;  
 #5 x=1;  
 #28 x=0;  
 #20 x=1;  
 #10 x=0;  
 #10 x=1;  
 #150 $finish;   
end  

always begin  
 #5 clk = ~clk;  
end  

endmodule:moore_mealy
```

Output Waveform:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your Moore machine you set the 'z' in the combinatorial section. At the same time as you set the state to C. Thus the two coincide. To get z high after two bits have been detected (thus after the state C) you must move the assignment into the clocked section:

```
z <= (state==C) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;
// or even shorter:
z <= (state==C);
```

---

Your Mealy machine is a problem. The definition of Mealy brings with it that the input  defines the output directly. Thus Mealy dictates that you must use a combinatorial statement of the type:

assign z = some_condition_with_state && x;
   // or without assign in your always_comb section

The 'directly' means you can't really set 'z' **after** x has been high for two clocks as by that time it may have gone low again.

---

One last tip: Don't use variables like 'z' and 'x' as they are too easily confused with 1'bx and 1'bz.

Answer (score 0):

Let's discuss the Moore implementation.
You set the initial state to `A` with the condition that `x` has to be 1 on a rising clock edge for the transition to state `B`. Now have a look at your waveforms. the current state is `A`, then `x` goes high. With the next rising clock edge you switch to state `B`, so far so good. 
Now we await another rising clock edge before we change to state `C` where `z` is set to be high. Again we check the waveform and see that that's exactly what happens.

So the assignment of `z` does not happen after 2 clock cycles as you expect but after the 2nd rising edge of the clock.

This should help to solve the Mealy on your own.